# How do I deep copy a library item to another library?

Tags: client-object-model, .net

We have an outside document app (PCM) that has a nightly sync to our SharePoint server.  All contracts in PCM are synced into SP then we change the PCM document to a link to SP.  Recently, we have a need to copy certain files from our SP library to another library on the same site, then update the URL in PCM to point to the new location.

I am brand new to SP.  I am writing this in C# using CSOM and CAML Query.  My questions are:

1. IF I have the URL of the document I want, how do I get a ListItem from SP using that URL?
2. How do I deep copy that ListItem to a new library?

I've gone through several questions here that are "close" to what I am trying to do but this ListItem object is throwing me for a loop.  I can't inspect it nor can I confirm that I have all the fields for the content type included.

Any (a lot?) of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the listitem from URL:

```
 ListItem  item =  web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileRelativeUrl).ListItemAllFields;
```

And to copy item to another library follow:

http://sacarter.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/sync-files-sharepoint-files-across-web-applications-using-the-client-object-model/